# Reimplementing clojure's lazy seq

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to re implement Clojures lazyseqs as a learning exercise, I am trying to figure out what is going on in the LazySeq.java,

https://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/20090320/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java

this branch does not suppose to have chunking behavior, so my thinking is that it is suppose to call fn everytime first is called, but I can not figure out what `seq` call does? more specifically following line,

```
s = RT.seq(fn.invoke());
```

Answer (score 1):

The body of the `lazy-seq` macro is put into a function. When it's time to use the sequence the body produces, it just calls that function to execute the body. You can – more or less – reimplement `lazy-seq` by the following:

```
(defn simple-lazy-seq*
  [seq-producing-fn]
  (reify
    clojure.lang.Sequential
    clojure.lang.Seqable
    (seq [this] (seq (seq-producing-fn)))))

(defmacro simple-lazy-seq
  [& body]
  `(simple-lazy-seq* (fn [] ~@body)))
```

The `lazy-seq` from core provides also the `ISeq` interface, but this is not strictly necessary.

**Edit**: Doing things in pure Java.

```
static Seqable lazy_seq(IFn seq_generating_fn) {
    return new Seqable() {
        ISeq seq() {
            return RT.seq(seq_generating_fn.invoke());
        }
    }
}

YourClass.lazy_seq(new IFn() {
    Object invoke() {
        return thing.returning_the_seq();
    }
});
```

I'm not sure I got the syntactic details right, but it should be close. As you see there are some limitiations here. Eg. `thing` must be `final` IIRC. But I'm not that fluent in Java.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but how would you tackle this in pure java assuming you have a fn object that can be invoked.

Comment: @hamza-yerlikaya That's what the Java code does. See also the edit.